# Rotating a Polygon to its Minimal Height

Tags: polygon, computational-geometry, concave

I need to rotate a concave polygon to minimize its height. I've thinking about finding a line which is the minimal diameter of that polygon, then rotate it so that line is parallel with Y axis.

My question is how to find such a line? Or, is there any other algorithm to rotate a polygon to so that its height is minimized?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ARRAY points := {P1, P2, ..., PN};

 points.delete(middle vertices of any collinear sequence of three points);

 REAL p_a := index of vertex with minimum y-coordinate;
 REAL p_b := index of vertex with maximum y-coordinate;

 REAL rotated_angle := 0;
 REAL min_width := INFINITY;

 VECTOR caliper_a(1,0);    // Caliper A points along the positive x-axis
 VECTOR caliper_b(-1,0);   // Caliper B points along the negative x-axis

 WHILE rotated_angle < PI

   // Determine the angle between each caliper and the next adjacent edge in the polygon
   VECTOR edge_a(points[p_a + 1].x - points[p_a].x, points[p_a + 1].y - points[p_a].y);
   VECTOR edge_b(points[p_b + 1].x - points[p_b].x, points[p_b + 1].y - points[p_b].y);
   REAL angle_a := angle(edge_a, caliper_a);
   REAL angle_b := angle(edge_b, caliper_b);
   REAL width := 0;

   // Rotate the calipers by the smaller of these angles
   caliper_a.rotate(min(angle_a, angle_b));
   caliper_b.rotate(min(angle_a, angle_b));

   IF angle_a < angle_b
     p_a++;  // This index should wrap around to the beginning of the array once it hits the end
     width = caliper_a.distance(points[p_b]);
   ELSE
     p_b++;  // This index should wrap around to the beginning of the array once it hits the end
     width = caliper_b.distance(points[p_a]);
   END IF

   rotated_angle = rotated_angle + min(angle_a, angle_b);

   IF (width < min_width)
     min_width = width;

   END IF
 END WHILE

 RETURN min_width;
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers

Also check out: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7844-geom2d/content/geom2d/polygons2d/minimumCaliperDiameter.m

Note: Both of these problems solve the **convex** case. To solve the **concave** case, you merely transform your inputs from conave to convex by doing the following:

```
1. Compute convex hull of your concave polygon.
2. Run algorithm above on convex polygon.
3. Once minimum height found, rotate.
4. Transform back to concave polygon.
```

The convex hull is very common in Python. You can use: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html

If you aren't comfortable using this library, you can use this algorithm to convert your concave shape to convex: (this is not meant to be used, just really bad pseudocode for you to understand how convex hull is computed)

```
Traverse vertices of concave polygon in clockwise order
_prev = starting vertex of traversal
_middle = second vertex in traversal
FOR _next vertex in traversal:
  IF _prev -> _middle -> _next make right turn (i.e. concave part)
     Connect _prev and _next and set _middle = _next
  ELSE
     Shift _prev to _middle and _middle to _next.
```

In other words, you just remove concave parts :)

Comment: I need the one for concave polygon but both of them are for convex polygon. And it is stated in the wikipedia that the method is for " determining all antipodal pairs of points and vertices on a convex polygon."

Comment: The convex algorithm solves your concave problem by transforming the concave polygon to a convex polygon using the convex hull. I have updated my answer with the algorithm for you.